# How to make Right To Left Translation animation with ViewPropertyAnimation?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am trying to show a fragment with right to left animation, as though it is coming from the right side of the screen but my code does exactly the opposite.

```
flBackground.animate().setDuration(250).x(0).translationX(0).alpha(1).start();
```

flBackground here is the id of the root view in my fragment.

I played with 'translationX' method. I gave the screen width in pixels, but my fragment got off screen. Is there a way in ViewPropertyAnimation that I can set initial positioning of a view to animate from?

I only want to use ViewPropertyAnimation, not other Animation objects. Other ones are quite big and I want simple code for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()`. It's the best way.

Example:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_right, R.animator.slide_left)
        .add(R.id.list_fragment_container, YourFragment.instance())
        .commit()
```

More: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)